# Cannot start SQL Server PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

Have you guys had this problem where, when you start PowerShell from SQL Server, it throws an exception like the following?

> Cannot resolve alias 'cd' because it
>   refers to term
>   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Manag
>   ement\Set-Location', which is not
>   recognized as a cmdlet, function,
>   operable pr ogram, or script file.
>   Verify the term and try again. At
>   line:1 char:140
>   + &{[System.Console]::Title = 'SQL Server Powershell';Convert-UrnToPath
>   'Server
>   [@Name=''AIMLESS'']/Database[@Name=''AdventureWorks2008'']'|cd
>   <<<< }

I cannot navigate around with some common aliases like `pwd`, `cd`, etc.. even though `get-alias` clears shows that `cd` is `set-location` and `pwd` is `get-location`.

[image]

***[UPDATE]*** Alias cannot be set either
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I ran across this several months ago, but can't find it anymore after a quick search.  I believe the user's GAC some how got corrupted/mixed up.

Are you able to start a regular PowerShell session OK?

How you updated .NET versions?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with regular PowerShell on the same machine---I actually installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 1 installed on my machine and it also installed .NET v4.0.20506

Comment: So...  Did this problem start after you installed .NET 4?  The SQL minishell may have some hardcoded configs that cause it to break here.

How about trying the regular PowerShell console, then loading the SQL snapins.  If that works, then there may be an issue with the SQL minishell itself.

Comment: @Marco Shaw: I am not sure if the problem has started after installing .NET 4.0 since I never tried SQL PowerShell before installing it.  But if I were to speculate that seems to be case, since that "developer" machine is the only one with VS2010 and has the trouble.  From "Get-PSSnapIn", i can see that SQL snapins are loaded but let me try it again.

Comment: I had a SQL 2008 VM, and just loaded the latest .NET 4.0 without any problems.  One thing that seems odd is the error refers to "...ManagementWSet-Location...".  I don't the "W".  That should at least be a black-slash, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like a profile issue to me. I found an article(a) that talks about a similar problem caused by Powershell version 1 beta being installed at one time.

I would look through each of the files in the [profile chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx) to see which one is remapping those aliases on you. You could then rename the profile file to test if it was the problem. I am not exactly sure how you are starting Powershell, but if SQL Server is starting Powershell, you will want to look at it's user account's profile.

This should do it...

```
notepad '$env:windir\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1'
notepad '$env:windir\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
notepad '$env:UserProfile\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
notepad '$env:UserProfile\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
```

> (a) Profile.msh possible errors:
>
> If you load the profile.msh file, and
>   you have previously installed an
>   earlier version of Monad, then on
>   startup you may see a series of errors
>   like:
>
> set-alias : The AllScope option cannot
>   be removed from the alias 'cat'. At
>   C:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Documents\msh\profile.msh:9
>   char:10
>   + set-alias <<<< cat get-content
>
> To fix this, either delete the file
>   named ("C:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Documents\msh\profile.msh" in
>   this example), or remove all the
>   "set-alias" lines from it. Aliases
>   defined in profile.msh in earlier
>   versions of Monad are now defined
>   internally by Monad before the profile
>   is run; therefore, the definitions in
>   profile.msh will generate an error
>   attempting to redefine the alias.
>
> http://www.latenighthacking.com/archives/reference/PowerShellDocumentationPack_rc1/Windows%20PowerShell%20RC1%20release%20notes.htm

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your error again, the problem is likely the script that is being ran when you click "Start Powershell". You will need to find and fix him.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PowerShell Community Extensions? Unfortunately they use the default profile.ps1 file instead of Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. IF this is the case all you need to do is rename your Profile.ps1 to Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. SQLPS will not load the Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 profile only the host agnostic profile profile.ps1. There is work item for it here

http://www.codeplex.com/Pscx/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=18417

Comment: I don't have PSCX installed on my machine.  And actually, I don't even have a profile location - PS C:\Users\dance2die> ii (split-path $profile -Parent)
Invoke-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\dance2die\Documents\WindowsPowerShell' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:3
+ ii <<<<  (split-path $profile -Parent)